# Get value from agent failed: TCP successful, cannot establish TLS to ][0.0.0.0]:10050]: connection closed by peer

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-agent

The color of ZBX Availability is changing into red from green and getting following error message on Zabbix Active Check monitoring:

"Get value from agent failed: TCP successful, cannot establish TLS to ][0.0.0.0]:10050]: connection closed by peer"

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That's a passive item error, not active.

The 0.0.0.0 address likely comes from host interfaces - you should fix that. If you wanted to use active items, you still have passive ones configured - change them all, including LLD rules and LLD prototypes to active.